# How can I get notified if there is any network Activity?

Tags: android

If there is any network activity on the phone could I register to some intent filter and get notified of the events?

The arrows on top in the notification bar (both for wifi and hsdpa) move, So I am guessing there is some way to get notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to register for listener

```
((TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE))
 .listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE
                      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY);
```

in [Phonestatelistener.OnDataActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onDataActivity%28int%29) you will recieve callback

Comment: can give me an example? this function retur the int status?